# Gradle: Could not find actionbarsherlock @aar in a library project

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle

I have a build.gradle file in my library project, the content of it looks like below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'

.......
```

when I do **gradle build**, it gives error:

> Could not find com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0.

If I change the line "**apply plugin**" from '**android-library**' to '**android**', it can compile fine.

So is it a bug with the gradle android plugin? that it cannot find actionbarsherlock correctly in maven repository if it's from a library project?

Comment: Are you trying to create an Android Application Project or an Android Library Project?

Comment: @staaar this is the gradle file for the library project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select from Project Settings -> Gradle, "Use local gradle distribution" pointing to you local Gradle copy. Mine is 1.9 and I managed to make it work.